# C# create Object obj = new T()?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a superclass we can call `class A` and few subclasses, e.g. `class a1 : A`, `class a2 : A`, ... and `a6 : A`. In my `class B`, I have a set of methods that creates and adds one of the subclasses to a `List<A>`in `B`.

I want to shorten my code I have at the moment. So instead of writing

```
Adda1()
{
    aList.Add( new a1() );
}

Adda2()
{
    aList.Add( new a2() );
} 

...

Adda6()
{
    aList.Add( new a6() );
}
```

Instead I want to write something similar to this

```
Add<T>()
{
    aList.Add( new T() );  // This gives an error saying there is no class T.
}
```

Is that possible?

Is it also possible to constraint that `T` has to be of type `A` or one of its subclasses?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Lee's answer is correct.

The reason is that in order to be able to call `new T()` you need to add a `new()` constraint to your type parameter:

```
void Add<T>() where T : new()
{
     ... new T() ...
}
```

You also need a constraint `T : A` so that you can add your object of type `T` to a `List<A>`.

Note: When you use `new()` together with other contraints, the `new()` constraint must come **last**.

**Related**

- [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. This means that I can pass the class `A` as a type constraint. Is there a way that I can make it only possible to pass subclasses of `A` as a constraint?

Comment: @sehlstrom: No, but you can test that at runtime if you wish and throw an exception if someone passes an object of type `A`. You might also want to consider making `A` abstract.

Comment: Greate! So if `A` is abstract, I can't pass it? Or I can pass it, but i will not be possible to create an instance?

Comment: @sehlstrom: If it's abstract, then it's not possible to create instances of A. This means that at runtime any argument you give must have a type that is a subclass of A.

Comment: Who's Lee and what's Lee's answer?

Comment: Lee is Lee and Lee's answer is down there, unless it is not, in which case it is up there.

Answer (score 34):

```
public void Add<T>() where T : A, new()
{
    aList.Add(new T());
}
```

Comment: For more information, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.

Comment: Thanks, saved the day!