# Create default item in a list and return new item

Tags: c#, list

I would like to add a new item at the back of a list, and get the newly created item.

Let's assume that we could do something like this for one moment:

```
class Temp
{
    public string First { get;set;}
    public string Second { get;set;}
}
List<string> list = new List<string>();
var newItem = list.Push();
newItem.First="asd";
newItem.Second = "qwe;
```

this would be easier than

```
var newItem = new Temp();
newItem.First="asd";
newItem.Second = "qwe;
list.Add(newItem);
```

**especially when I can't use auto-properties.**

Is this possible?

Comment: Makes no sense what you are asking. please be clearer. you can add an item to the back of the list sure by using the Insert method of the List<T> and giving it the index to insert at

Answer (score 0):

You can use object initializers:

```
var list = new List<Temp>();
list.Add(new Temp{ First = "abc", Second = "def" });
```

Or together with a collection initializer:

```
var list = new List<Temp> { new Temp{ First = "abc", Second = "def" } };
```

This turns your four liner into a one liner.

Or with more than one entry:

```
var list = new List<Temp> {
    new Temp{ First = "abc", Second = "def" },
    new Temp{ First = "ghi", Second = "jkl" },
    new Temp{ First = "mno", Second = "pqr" }
};
```

And it should of course be a list of `Temp` instead of a list of `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you implement your own List type and add the Push method, the only way you can do that is if the `T` in List can be constructed using a parameterless constructor.

Here's an extension method for that.

**This is not recommended, but is an answer to your question.**

Something along the lines of this - *I did not compile or run this code*

```
public static class ListEx {
  public static T Push<T>(this List<T> list) where T: new() {
    // Create an instance of T.
    var instance = new T();
    // Add it to the list.
    list.Add(instance);
    // Return the new instance.
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: Or you can simply create an instance with `new T()`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11234485/880990

Comment: Oh, well there you go :D