# Generic method cast T to object type

Tags: c#

I have a method that accepts a generic type of BaseViewModel.
I want to get the actual object in the method.

What I tried:

```
public static void LogScreen<T>() where T : BaseViewModel
 {
    var viewModel = T as BaseViewModel;
 }
```

Comment: "the actual object", what do you mean? If you need an instance of an object, take it as a parameter. `void LogScreen<T>(T instance) ...`

Comment: Very unclear what you are looking for, could be duplicate of `new T()` ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234452/c-sharp-create-object-obj-new-t

Comment: There is something wrong with your idea or architecture if you need to get instance of defined type in generic function. Even if you are using "where T". You have a base type accepting by this function so you should use "public static void LogScreen(BaseViewModel baseViewModel)" instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not passing any object into the method, only the parameter **type**.

To apply value correctly, You should use the syntax like:

```
public static void LogScreen<T>(T TArg)
    where T : BaseViewModel
{
    var viewModel = TArg; //not necessary: as BaseViewModel;
}
```

In this kind of code You do not really need to use generic and You might go with simplier version as:

```
public static void LogScreen(BaseViewModel viewModel)
{
     //already got viewModel as correct type and checked during compile for types
}
```

---

**Note:** The big advantage of using generic approach is putting there some type and then work with the type whole time (great example `IEnumerable<int>`). If You would do that without generic type, You would need to use `object` everywhere and You would need to cast the object all the time

- Generic is advantage there as You can put anything inside.

On the other hand if You have a method, where You have only one type the only one, it is easier to go with strict parameter type (2nd approach).

---

Comment of **ZoharPeled** - the code should be written as:

```
public static void LogScreen<T>(T TArg)
    where T : BaseViewModel
{
    var viewModel = TArg as BaseViewModel;
    var viewModel2 = TArg;
}
```

From the compiler's point of view, the type of the reference named `viewModel` is exactly the same as the type of the reference named `viewModel2` - both are `BaseViewModel`, and both instances may or may not be of any type derived from `BaseViewModel`. Long story short, the as operator is redundant in this code. Even if you pass an instance of some class derived from `BaseModelView` you can only reference it as a `BaseModelView` in this method.

Comment: `var viewModel = TArg as BaseViewModel;` should be `var viewModel = TArg;`, since `TArg` is already `BaseViewModel` or deriving from it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled replied in Q.

Comment: Well, as much as I like to read my name in **bold** font, your edit is wrong. From the compiler's point of view, the type of the reference named `viewModel` is exactly the same as the type of the reference named `viewModel2` - both are `BaseViewModel`, and both instances may or may not be of any type derived from `BaseViewModel`. Long story short, the `as` operator is redundant in this code. Even if you pass an instance of some class derived from `BaseModelView` you can only reference it as a `BaseModelView` in this method.

Comment: @ZoharPeled alright, checked in code and I have to apologize. Again the day wasn't useless. Thanks!

Comment: No apologies needed. Neither of us holds the absolute knowledge about c#, and I'm sure I can learn things from you just as you where able to learn something from me. I think that's what this community is all about.